# Get the JAX-RS application a resource is attached on

Tags: jax-rs

I wonder if it's possible to get an instance of the JAX-RS `Application` a resource is attached on. Ideally a way that isn't dependent to a specific implementation. For example using dependency injection...

Thanks very much for your help,
Thierry

Comment: What do you mean by the application? Do you mean the `Application`? If so, as specified, you an inject `@Context Application`, but it will most likely not be the actual instance, but a proxy (from I've experienced). But if you're looking to alter anything on it, I don't think it's possible. It will be read only

Comment: Yes, I mean `Application` ;-) So you answered my question. If you want, you can post an answer so I can accept it. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [The Spec](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec.html)

> **5.2.1 Application**
>
> The instance of the application-supplied `Application` subclass can be injected into a class field or method parameter using the `@Context` annotation. Access to the `Application` subclass instance allows configuration information to be centralized in that class. Note that this cannot be injected into the `Application` subclass itself since this would create a circular dependency.

but from I've experienced, it will most likely not be the actual instance, but a proxy. Also if you're looking to alter anything on it, I'm not sure it's possible. It might be read-only.