# Application/Deployment specific properties with JAX-RS and WildFly

Tags: java, configuration, jax-rs, resteasy, wildfly

I am used to Spring on Tomcat/Jetty and I now work on an existing JAX-RS project running on WildFly (RESTEasy).

I would like to know where do the application/deployment property files go on WildFly, standalone/configuration/myapp.properties?

Then how does the application load them? I tried in our class extending javax.ws.rs.core.Application:

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> get properties");
        // I added this method but nothing is printed...
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> get classes");
        // This is printed
        ...
        // classes are loaded correctly
    }
}
```

Then how would I access the properties in the controllers? By the way we don't use dependency injection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### *Some Investigation...*

Normally what *should* work

1. The `getProperties()` should be called on startup to load any required application properties.
2. You should be able to inject [`javax.ws.rs.core.Configuration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Configuration.html) into your resource classes (with `@Context`) and retrieve properties through that object. This is stated in the javadoc

   > This interface can be injected using the `Context` annotation.

#### Test

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RestApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> get properties");
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put("message", "Hello Configuration Properties!");
        return props;
    }
}

@Path("config")
public class ConfigResource {

    @Context
    private Configuration configuration;

    @GET
    public Response getProperty(@QueryParam("prop") String prop) {
        String propValue = (String)configuration.getProperty(prop);
        return Response.ok(propValue).build();
    }
}
```

#### Discoveries

- The above doesn't work from what I tested with Resteasy 3.0.9.Final. I get some error about no context for this type. I don't know why. Might be a bug, I don't know. Maybe something you can look into.
- The above works fine with Jersey 2.16

#### What works with Resteasy

What I *could* get to work with Resteasy is to inject `Application` (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29675294/2587435) into the resource (also with `@Context`) and get the properties that way.

```
@Path("config")
public class ConfigResource {

    @Context 
    Application application;

    @GET
    public Response getProperty(@QueryParam("prop") String prop) {
        String propValue = (String)application.getProperties().get(prop);
        return Response.ok(propValue).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I also get an error when I use Configuration with RESTEasy 3.0.10.Final. The problem with @Context Application application is that it loads the properties from the file every time we call getProperties(), it's not "cached".

Comment: Don't load the properties from there then. Do it in the constructor. That was a bad example on my part. Sorry. With the `Configuration` object it doesn't work that way though. Properties are loaded from the getProperties into the `Configuration`. I'm curious why it doesn't work with Resteasy though.

Comment: Probably because RESTEasy is crap? ;-) I don't really want to use a constructor, this Application class should work as is without constructors. I ended up loading the properties in a static block in a utils class... Thank you for your time and if I find a fix (or a better way to do) I'll let you know.