# How to get registered jaxrs resources instances

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I have registered my jax-rs resource classes in my REST `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`class, registering them in `getSingleTons()` method.

How can I get programatically reference to my registered resources instances ?

Comment: Where are you trying to reference them from? If it's inside another JAX-RS component, you can inject `Application` as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29675294/2587435).